# TypeError when getting assets in Rails 7

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm running Rails 7. When I start the server and make a connection, I'm getting an error when the browser attempts to get an asset. It's a different asset every time. Sometimes it's one asset, sometimes 2 assets, sometimes **no assets**. Any asset could be affected, it's completely random. For example:

```
2022-02-25 16:03:54 -0800 Rack app ("GET /assets/turbo.min-96cbf52c71021ba210235aaeec4720012d2c1df7d2dab3770cfa49eea3bb09da.js" - (::1)): #<TypeError: nil can't be coerced into Float>
2022-02-25 16:03:54 -0800 Rack app ("GET /assets/inter-font-8c3e82affb176f4bca9616b838d906343d1251adc8408efe02cf2b1e4fcf2bc4.css" - (::1)): #<TypeError: nil can't be coerced into Float>
```

I have no clue which nil is being coerced into a float. How would I even begin to debug this?

Comment: I think this is related to https://github.com/rails/rails/issues/44167

Comment: A quick fix is to set `config.server_timing = false` in `config/development.rb`

Comment: Yup, I think that’s it. I was noticing the same thing in production as well though.